# Zooming on UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` which I'm using to display a variety of content, sometimes HTML and sometimes PDF/Powerpoint/etc (which is all seemingly handled by the same underlying control).

What I want to do is harness the underlying `UIScrollView` (a subview of the `UIWebView`) to capture the exact perspective of the scroll view and recreate the scroll position in another `UIWebView`, thus keeping them both in sync.

The problem that I'm having is that the `zoomScale` property of the `UIScrollView` is always `1.0` while displaying HTML content (though when displaying PDF content, `zoomScale` is correct).

I managed to find that the only place where I can get any inkling of the zoom scale of an HTML page is in the `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:` delegate method. I've found that the `atScale:` argument seems to provide a *relative* zoom scale, to what the zoom scale was before the zooming operation began. So for example when zooming in, that argument is >1, and when zooming out it is <1, and it seems to be a relative value between the two zoom scales rather than an absolute zoom scale).

What I've further found is that fundamentally, HTML and PDF content is handled by two different underlying views: there's `UIWebBrowserView` which handles HTML content, and `UIWebPDFView` to handle displaying of PDFs.

So in other words, when using a `UIWebPDFView`, the `zoomScale` property of the `UIScrollView` is completely reliable (e.g. `1.0` for zoomed-out, `2.4` for zoomed-in, for example). On the other hand, `UIWebBrowserView` is much more fiddly, and when asking the `UIScrollView` for its `zoomScale`, always returns `1.0`, but when receiving the delegate callback, receives a scale value that is a relative value.

So my questions are:-

1. Is this a bug? (This behaviour is seen on both iOS 4 and 5 from what I've seen).
2. How can I get both the `zoomScale` (or some other property/properties) for both HTML and PDF content, and get it in such a way that the state can be duplicated and kept in sync with another `UIWebView`.

I'm not beholden to using `zoomScale`, so I'm open to other suggestions for how the scroll state of a `UIWebView` can be captured and reproduced on another `UIWebView`.

Comment: please note my answer

Comment: Your answer is noted, but it doesn't have any relevance to this issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When loading HTML, and `UIWebBrowserView` is being used, you can use

`zoomScale = 1.0 / webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale`

Of course this is assuming that you can reliably ensure that the minimum zoom of your HTML page is 1.0, since some pages can alter the minimum zoom using the "viewport" meta tag.

Comment: This actually works well in terms of getting a reliable, absolute zoom scale. The only question is what to transfer over to the other `UIScrollView` to keep them synced up. I've tried copying the `zoomScale` and `minimumZoomScale` properties over to the other scroll view but this doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Unfortunately the only way I know how is by setting the zoom value in the "viewport" meta tag in HTML. This can also be done in Javascript, but requires a page reload to take effect. I'm assuming you want to do this in real time, so this might not be of much help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however as you say I need it in realtime. Nevertheless I'll have a play with it and post back here any updates.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this?

```
set scalesPageToFit=YES;
```

That's the most common way to deal with the problem i think. Setting that enables you to pinch and zoom UIWebView.I don't think you can actually zoom in/out UIWebView without that.

Now the zoom is going to be relative to whatever you're showing on your UIWebView. If it is a big table, it's not so close but it's a good start point if you're going to pinch for zoom in.

Answer (score 4):

> **This Logic for zooming of UIWebView, no need to add UIWebView on UIScrollView**

Well only problem with `webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;` is, it change initial content font size but          I have got other option by my self, Its working very well for me.

Add `<UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>` to your **.h file**

Creation of your `UIWebView.`

```
self.mWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
self.mWebview.delegate = self; /// set delegate method of UIWebView
self.mWebview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 35, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - 80); // set frame whatever you want..
[self.mWebview setOpaque:NO];
self.mWebview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.mWebview];
```

With load HTML file/content.

```
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File Name"ofType:@"html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.mWebview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Webview Delegate Methods

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    webView.scrollView.delegate = self; // set delegate method of UISrollView
    webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 20; // set as you want.
    webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1; // set as you want.

    //// Below two line is for iOS 6, If your app only supported iOS 7 then no need to write this.
    webView.scrollView.zoomScale = 2;
    webView.scrollView.zoomScale = 1;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UIScrollView Delegate Methods

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
    self.mWebview.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 20; // set similar to previous.
}
```

> **NOTE:** I had to tested on Mac OS X - 10.9.3 with Xcode 5.1.1 and iOS version 6.1 and latter.

I hope this will helpful for you. :)

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but your answer solved a couple of things for me. However, the `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:` seems to allow the user to continue to zoom forever but at 20 at a time. How can I allow the zoom to stop absolutely at 20? I have a question regarding this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977020/ios-uiwebview-does-not-zoom-enough

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the only way I found to get the actual scale of the web content in a UIWebView is by accessing to a private member of the UIWebBrowserView : initialScale.

```
float initialScale = (access to [UIWebBrowserView initialScale])
float zoomScale = 1.0 / webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale;
float actualScale = zoomScale * initialScale;
```

I am wondering if this can be done without accessing to private member.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little late but for those who need to determine whether the current UIWebView contains  HTML. A method I wrote to determine this was below. I called this immediately after the webView has loaded

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if (!webViewIsHTMLHasBeenSet) {
        webViewIsHTML = [self containsWebBrowserView];
        NSLog(@"webViewIsHTML = %@",webViewIsHTML ? @"YES": @"NO");
    }
}

- (BOOL)containsWebBrowserView {
    BOOL result = NO;
    for (UIView * WVSubview in [webView.scrollView subviews]) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([WVSubview class]) isEqualToString:@"UIWebBrowserView"]) {
            result = YES;
            webViewIsHTMLHasBeenSet = YES;
            return result;
        }
    }
    webViewIsHTMLHasBeenSet = YES;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just simply set,

`scalesPageToFit=YES` for pich zoom  on a UIWebView