# iOS UIWebView Does Not Zoom Enough

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I have `UIWebView` and have `[[self webView] setScalesPageToFit:YES]`.

### Problem

When **zooming** in my `webView` the zoom isn't as magnified as it is on Safari.

### Question

How can I accomplish the same zoom factor that Safari has?

### Examples

This is what the first sentence at url http://www.apple.com/privacy/ looks like at max zoom:

**On my `webView`**
[image: first sentence at url http://www.apple.com/privacy/ at max zoom on my webview]

**On Safari**
[image: first sentence at url http://www.apple.com/privacy/ at max zoom on safari]

Comment: how do you specify the max zoom ?

Comment: well I tried `[[self webView] setContentScaleFactor:10.0f]` when view loads

Comment: did that answer your question?