# User scalable with PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using PhoneGap 3.0 (CLI) to build a PhoneGap application.

I am also using jQuery Mobile with it. I am facing issue with allowing a particular page "user-scalable"

Meta viewport is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

It works well when viewing it on mobile browser, but in the PhoneGap application it does not allow scaling.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579078/phonegap-scaling-down-a-webpage-with-viewport

Comment: That one is for Phonegap (iOS). I could not find a solution that is independent of the OS. I managed to use Hammer js and manage the catch pinch in/out and scale the web page

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, Phonegap( Android) open index.html in WebView, if you want to scaling then you must enable SupportZoom. In MainActivity, add codes:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    //Enable zoom in WebView
    WebSettings settings = super.appView.getSettings();
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
}
```

And in UIWebView (iOS), you can seeing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255621/how-to-allow-zooming-of-uiwebview-tried-everything) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219685/how-can-i-enable-zoom-in-on-uiwebview-which-inside-the-uiscrollview)

Comment: I could not find a solution that is independent of the OS. I managed to use Hammer js and manage the catch pinch in/out and scale the web page.

Comment: Oh. Did you use Hammer.js correctly? You must test in browser if it working good and in iOS device it not working then UIWebView not enable zoom. You can seeing [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219685/how-can-i-enable-zoom-in-on-uiwebview-which-inside-the-uiscrollview)

Comment: I have yet to test it on iOS. I am not sure whether I will test it. The project we are working on is to develop iOS Native APP and Phonegap for Android, Windows & Blackberry.

I am might test on iOS in month if I see a free time and post a feedback here.

Comment: I only working pinch zoom in Android and iOS, and i must config( rewrite several code, plugin and native feature) for each platform. So that, I think you must config for each platform. Noway pinch zoom independent with js.